# Is it possible to return a list from an iterator block?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, yield

I have this function:

```
class Path : List<LineSegment> { }

private IEnumerable<LineSegment> GetLineSegments(CollisionType collisionType, Path path)
{
    if (collisionType == CollisionType.End)
    {
        yield return path.First();
        yield return path.Last();
    }
    else if (collisionType == CollisionType.Segment)
    {
        foreach (LineSegment lineSegment in path)
        {
            yield return lineSegment;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I am checking for collision (between ball and line) in two ways. In one case I only want to check the end points of the drawn path, but in the other case I want to return each line segment in the entire path.

It seems to be a bit weird to loop through the given list just to return the entire list. Can I just return the list? I'd like to be able to do something like this but I'm getting errors:

```
private IEnumerable<LineSegment> GetLineSegments(CollisionType collisionType, Path path)
{
    if (collisionType == CollisionType.End)
    {
        yield return path.First();
        yield return path.Last();
    }
    else if (collisionType == CollisionType.Segment)
    {
        return path.AsEnumerable<LineSegment>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no choice but to use a `foreach` loop.  It's a somewhat frequently requested feature, but one that is not in the language.

Comment: Ok thanks I have an alternative anyway. `IEnumerable<LineSegment> segments = collisionType == CollisionType.Segment ? path : new List<LineSegment>() { path.First(), path.Last() };` Probably cleaner so it's all good.

Comment: @JohnSmith Note that that's semantically different.  As that is not an iterator block the code is executed eagerly, rather than being deferred until the iterator is enumerated.  If you don't care, that's fine, just realize that the two aren't the same thing.

Comment: Yeah it happens to not matter in my case but good to point out for future readers.

Comment: It's a requested feature, but it doing so would be really hard (as in damn near impossible).  When you use 'yield return' it fundamentally changes the way the compiler parses and compiles that method.  In fact, behind the scenes, it basically creates a private class that implements IEnumerable<whatever>, and encodes that method in it with some wizardry to replicate the behavior *as if* the function was re-entrant at the 'yield return's.

Comment: @CleverNeologism It would not be impossible at all.  It would in fact be rather straightforward to do.  The syntax would likely need to be different, the use of `yield foreach <sequence of things to yield>` is one suggestion that's frequently used, and that would ensure that the lexer/parser won't have problems.  As for implementation, it'd pretty much just refactor it into what's here, creating a loop and yielding each item within it.  It could throw in a few performance optimizations that wouldn't be possible without a language feature, which is partly why it'd be nice to have.

Comment: That's not what he asked.  He asked to be able to have a function that is both an iterator (on one execution path) and a simple function that returns a concrete IEnumerable on another path.  To even begin to do that, the compiler would need to guarantee you would never "switch modes" during enumeration.  What you are doing is just syntactic sugar... the method remains an iterator.

Comment: @CleverNeologism The OP made it clear that he didn't *care* about the semantics of eager/deferred execution one way or another.  It's not important to him to have one execution path that defers execution and another that does.  The question never states that it's important that, in the event the entire list needs to be yielded, that it be evaluated and returned eagerly and *not* deferred.